# page is not scrolling by touch vertically in mobile devices

Tags: css, html, devise

I am working on www.pozitive.energy website. here i get an issue of mobile devise scrolling vertically.

I am using two divs, one for desktop, laptop and tablet device and another for mobile device. first div tag is perfectly works.

I have already used skrollr and delete a height=100% overflow:hidden;

Please help me!
Its already online [www.pozitive.energy](http://www.pozitive.energy)

Comment: you have a number of js errors when viewing in the browser, it would probably be best to use something like https://modernizr.com/ to detect device, and load just what you need. I would also recommend http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html to detect swiping, and use it to fire the scrollr changes

Comment: Thank you for reply.:)
Reason for not working is clashing of js.